# URL of an stored image in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Excuse, maybe it could be simple for some peopl but I'm having a lot of troubles doing it. The thing is I have stored some images in my database in MySQL, I can display them in my pages, but it is by printing them with a php script, but my problem is:
* I have to send emails, in one table I have the structure, that is, I have all the components like title, message and some images, I can call this components but I want to get the url of my stored images because I can't just print the image in the email structure, this is what I'm trying:

```
 $link =  mysqli_connect("host","user","pass");
    mysqli_select_db($link, "db");
 $result1 = mysqli_query($link , "select binaryFile from img where    idImg='$idIMG' ");

 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
 {
    $imgp = $row["binaryFile"];
 }
```

- I read the image, but what I want is the url of it. If someone can help me I would be very glad with you. Thanks!

Comment: If you stored the image itself in the database rather than its location, there is no url to get.

Comment: So, there is no possibility to get the url?

Comment: The url would need to be a url pointing to a page that reads the file from the db and servers it as a binary file like `example.com/image.php?id=imageid` ... either that, or extract the files from the db to the filesystem (under htdocs so they can be reached via a url), and then store the location in the db so you can have a direct url...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're storing images in your database in binary format, there will be no url for them.

However, you say you're printing them with a php script. You can use that script as a URL (assuming its webhosted).  Set it up as a proxy and use the url to that script as your url. So something like:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['image_id']))
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    die;
}

$link =  mysqli_connect("host","user","pass", "db");

$safe_id = $db->real_escape_string($idIMG);
$result = $link->query("SELECT binaryFile FROM img WHERE idImg='". $safe_id ."' LIMIT 1");

if ($result->num_rows == 0)
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    die;
}

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$image_data = $row['binaryFile'];

header('Content-Type: image/jpg');

// Print image data here directly out to the browser
//...

?>
```

If you named this script "image_proxy.php", then you could use "http://your.domain/image_proxy.php?image_id=12345" as the url you include in emails.